# Can I attach vinyl siding to a concrete foundation with Tapcons?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I have a question about adding vinyl siding to my existing home.  I live in a new home (< 1 year old) with a walkout basement.  The house currently has siding on the first floor stopping at the foundation. This leaves about 500-600 square feet of the poured concrete foundation exposed. My wife and I are considering ways of improving the look of the foundation by adding siding to grade.  We have received a quote from a contractor (who did the original siding) for what I feel is a very reasonable price.

I have a couple concerns about the siding addition.  The concrete foundation is nearly flush with the first floor siding meaning that using furring strips would cause the new siding to stick out.  The contractor proposed using Tapcons to attach the siding directly to the foundation which would allow the siding to line up with the first floor.  This being the only alternative makes sense to me, however I am concerned about 300-400 holes being drilled into the side of my foundation.  I am also concerned that it will be problematic if the siding ever needs replaced. I wanted to get some opinions about whether this was ok to do?  Or whether this cosmetic improvement is not worth any potential problems it could create? I have been unable to find much advice on this subject as most discussions rightly assume furring strips are usable.

Comment: I'd just paint the foundation the same color as the siding and do some landscaping (topiary or a flat trellis). A lot cheaper and a lot less problematic.

Comment: +1 to filling and painting - much cheaper, much more maintainable and you don't have a gaillion holes and gazillion anchors weakening the foundation. Concrete paints are very durable these days.

Comment: Fake rock mortored on wall would look good

Comment: Vinyl siding usually isn't an improvement :) (yes, I know, that's mainly a matter of opinion...)

Comment: But if paint is just not enough, you could consider stucco. That'd be much more appropriate than Vinyl siding, IMHO, and would offer a nice finished surface that would also add a bit of contrast (in a good way) with the existing vinyl siding above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not, but that is a lot of little holes in the foundation and also lots of work.

You would have to make sure the tapcons are not too tight as well so the vinyl doesn't buckle.

I would do as others have suggested and add some plants/landscaping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. I live so far away from U, (Santiago, Chile, SouthAmerica). In fact let me tell U many houses here are made in concret and blocks (like mine one 'cause of earthquakes). Well, I decided to add Siding pvc (manufactured by DVP a Chilean company bassed on American and Canadian products) and the way is putting a kind of frame of 2" board (not necesary brushed), vertical and horizontally,like a huge window. But each 60cms (24") boards, adding to concret throw a 4" "dowel-nail" (is a screw that put whith a hammer wich has a dowel included when U buy it). Well, in those boards you will add sidings throw wood-nails (big head 1" long aprox. utilizable normally when sidding is put on MDF new houses. I hope I can help U from my experience.